# can I block specific website on safari using content blocker extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, safari-content-blocker

I am working on a content blocker extension in an iOS app. I already blocked specific content on some website, but can I block the whole website using a content blocker extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution.

```
[{
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
         },
         "trigger": {
            "url-filter": ".*reddit.*"
            
         }
}]
```

write this code in the content blocker extension of JSON file.

Comment: did you send me one demo that you are give block some website advertisment ?

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think the purpose of the blocker extension is to block a specific `webSite`.

> In iOS, a Content Blocker extension customizes the way Safari and
>   Safari View Controller handle your content. The extension tailors your
>   content by hiding elements, blocking loads, and stripping cookies from
>   Safari requests.

You should instead handle the URL-block in the

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType
```

And make your controls in there. An examlple:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let url = request.URL?.absoluteString
    if  url ==  "http://www.test.com"{
       return false
    }
    return true
}
```